# Is Ant-Man and The Wasp happening after Infinity War in MCU timeline?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, ant-man-and-the-wasp

[*Avengers: Infinity War*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avengers:_Infinity_War) is set to release in 25 April 2018 and [*Ant-Man and the Wasp*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant-Man_and_the_Wasp) is set to release in 6 July 2018.

I haven't seen Ant-Man or Wasp in the Infinity War trailers( *yet :)* ), and looking at the release dates (we can't never say which movie happens first on the timeline with release dates though) ,

So, where is in the timeline of MCU Ant-Man and The Wasp going to happen?

Comment: I can't say for definite - but, generally, the movies happen in release order (though exact dates are fuzzy, and there are two obvious exceptions - Captain America: The First Avenger, and the Guardians of the Galaxy movies) - but this probably won't be answerable until the movies come out and the stories provide the necessary clues.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Signs point to *Ant-Man & The Wasp* taking place sometime leading up to and/or during Infinity War

First, the most recent trailer starts off with Scott and Hope discussing the events of *Civil War*.

Additionally, [Marvel's official synopsis](http://marvel.com/movies/movie/245/ant-man_and_the_wasp) specifically describes it as taking place in the aftermath of *Civil War*.

> From the Marvel Cinematic Universe comes a new chapter featuring heroes with the astonishing ability to shrink: “Ant-Man and The Wasp.” **In the aftermath of “Captain America: Civil War,”** Scott Lang (Paul Rudd) grapples with the consequences of his choices as both a Super Hero and a father. As he struggles to rebalance his home life with his responsibilities as Ant-Man, he’s confronted by Hope van Dyne (Evangeline Lilly) and Dr. Hank Pym (Michael Douglas) with an urgent new mission. Scott must once again put on the suit and learn to fight alongside The Wasp as the team works together to uncover secrets from their past.

If the movie were to take place post-Infinity War, the official synopsis, at the very least would likely read differently.

### In an interview with Seth Meyers, Paul Rudd revealed that the movie takes place "kind of concurrently" with *Infinity War*

> “**[Ant-Man and The Wasp] happens kind of concurrently and it’s very important because it doesn’t exist in a vacuum.** You have to stay through to the end because once you see this thing through those post-credit scenes — there’s some mind-blowing stuff in there that kind of ties into Infinity War and it’s uh — I think I messed up. I think I messed up, yeah.”

Comment: We cannot know yet whether this is a spoiler, a mistake or something else, but in Infinity War, they mention having an "ant and a spider", but no wasp. This may or may not mean that this answer is wrong.

Answer (score 8):

Spoilers ahead, having seen the movie today.

> During the first mid-credits scene, Hank, Janet, and Hope all get dusted. Accounting for how long it took them to build the quantum tunnel featured in this scene,

it would seem that the events of the movie take place leading up to and during *Infinity War*. This is further proven at the beginning of the film, where it’s established that this takes place close to two years after *Civil War*.

Answer (score 1):

After the Civil War, Scott has been house arrested for Two Years. (If he tries to escape his imprisonment would be for 20 years). The Movie Ant-Man and the Wasp are just before the Event of Infinity War, (Which is understood by the post-credits scene of AntMan and the Wasp)

Answer (score 1):

##### No. *Ant-Man and the Wasp* takes place before *Avengers: Infinity War*, not after.

This is revealed by the book [*Marvel Studios’ The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline*](https://marvelcinematicuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Studios%27_The_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe:_An_Official_Timeline), which gives a chronological order of the events in the MCU. According to the book, the events of *Ant-Man and the Wasp* occur before Thanos attacks Xandar and seizes the Power Stone. In *Infinity War*, we see that Thanos starts with the Power Stone in his possession, so that means *Ant-Man and the Wasp* (not including the events in the mid-credits scene) has already taken place.

[image: relevant page from The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline] [image: relevant page from The Marvel Cinematic Universe: An Official Timeline]