# Reason for Ant-Man not appearing in Infinity War

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, ant-man-and-the-wasp

Having watched *Ant-Man and the Wasp* I cannot see any decent reason why Ant-Man was not included.

In the beginning of *Avengers: Infinity War*, it's mentioned that Scott took a plea bargain, and this is played out in *Ant-Man and the Wasp*, 2 years house arrest and 5 years probation.

Without explaining the film entirely, stuff happens but towards the end of the film, he has this heart to heart with his daughter about helping people vs finishing his house arrest and staying clean. The outcome is that he suits up to save the day.

At the end, everyone is fine and there is a montage of people doing stuff, Scott having his tag removed, his friends doing stuff in their office, Scott takes Cassie out for the day. Hurrah happy ending!!

As the post credits scene reveals, this all happened pre-snap of doom. We see a scene where Scott is Ant-Man again, hanging out with the Pyms (which is a violation of his parole) and about to do some more Quantum Realm stuff. Then the Snap happens.

Given that we know there is a clear few days between the end of the action in the film and the finger Click of Doom, I feel there is no good reason for him not to be involved.

Here are 2 reasons I have heard and why I feel they don't stand up:

a) He is on probation and didn't want to be seen publicly. - In the film he has run this risk multiple times and even goes Goliath size to mess with a ferry in the water. I think he would accept the risk given the attacks in New York.

b) The Avengers don't call him and respect his plea deal. - I think the Avengers still watch T.V./The News and would have seen him as Ant-Man and so would've been aware that he happy being Ant-Man. They would have called to say "Hey, I see you still being Ant-Man, we need you if you want to come?"
Even if they don't ring him, do you think he would have ignored the attacks in New York mess around on a roof top with a Van Sized Quantum Tunnel?

Has anyone read any other reasons why Ant-Man wasn't in *Avengers: Infinity War* that still makes sense?

Comment: Related: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/85455/is-ant-man-and-the-wasp-happening-after-infinity-war-in-mcu-timeline

Comment: Distinctly related https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/90254/

Comment: Infinity war movie took place most of the time in outer space and wakanda, and everything happened so fast, even nick fury didn't know actually what happened

Answer (score 8):

In Infinity War When asked where Hawkeye and Ant Man are, Cap and the team (i think it was Romanoff actually) state that they took a plea deal to see their family, now while this could be seen as the team disagreeing with that decision by the way its reacted to, it more likely that they don't want to cause issues for Barton and Scott's plea deals, that basically ties it up lore wise.

While yes they would be able to see things on TV, this all happens at the same time. all of the celebrating in the ExCon office seems to take place the day after Scott's probation ends, and so does the Cassie trip. so this is only 1 day at most after his freedom, Cassie trip was likely same day, its possible celebration as well. What we don't know is how long after his release the post credit scene takes place. but it is likely a couple of days or more as they had to build a new machine. but remember the rest of the Film only takes place over 2 days

But once the severity of the events in IW is known its possibly only a day or two between the end of A&TW and the Big Click, so that would mean that the events in Edinburgh have already taken place, and from then everything happens so fast in IW that they may have changed their minds but wouldn't have had time to get him to Wakanda, or just they were too busy to think about calling him

**Below is potentially a major spoiler for the next Avengers film, do not look at if you don't want it**

> This is theory at the moment but there are pictures of Ant-Man during the Battle for New York in Avengers Assemble, which means he travels in time through one of the time portals mentioned in the post credit scene. so it seems that AntMan is key to saving the day in the next second part of infinity war, so its probably that the produceers decided to have him not be in the first one means they don't need to risk the whole "having 2 Antmen" as once in sections of IW

Comment: There is something jarring about how casual they are on the roof in the post credits. At that point the large scale attack in New York would have been noticed as well as the News Coverage of Iron Man leaving earth (I think there was a spot of a t.v showing this) and the 4 of them are happily focussed more on their science experiment rather than an alien attack.

Comment: I didn't see the TV bit, but I've not got round to seeing it a second time yet, so may not have noticed. while i agree, the news reports in IW are shown they show that Iron Man is missing, thats it, there would have been no news out of Wakanda, the effects on Edinburgh were minor so unlikely to get global coverage. Pim hates Stark, for past reasons and that because of Stark they are now on the run. So he wouldn't be upset to think he was missing, so they only know a ship turned up and stark went missing. so i think it actually fits the characters fairly well

Comment: Hank without Janet, yes I can see him ignoring the plight of Stark, but Hope and the returned Janet? From what we've seen Janet is the counter to Hank and she would certainly care that this was happening. It feels like they aren't just ignoring, it feels like they don't know something has happened at all. A second Alien attack in New York should be on everyone's mind given the results of the first one. (On a side note there isn't a news report in Ant-Man 2 I was also referring to the news reports in IW don't going look for it in your second viewing ;P)

Comment: Maybe a throw away line like: Scott: Guy's should be really be doing this whilst everythings happening in New York? Hank: "Some snarky comment about Tony just like his Dad", Hope: "Awww, you upset good old Cap hasn't given you a call". Scott then just flusters away the situation embarrassed about being called out for calling him 'Cap'. That would allow the to acknowledge the situation but show there are reasons they haven't gone, Hank = Hatred, Scott = Embarrassed over not being called yet, Hope = Following Dad.

Comment: I'm not saying it couldn't have be done, but its possible that Janet hadn't seen the news, its likely she spent every waking moment since coming out with Hank and Hope, and not in front of the TV and like i said, Scott is not likely to pay attention to Stark much, if Cap got caught then it would be different